# CSS Dropdown menu cutoff by container in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, position, z-index, drop-down-menu

I have a very similar problem to this post:

[CSS Flyout menu gets cut off by borders of its container in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742828/css-flyout-menu-gets-cut-off-by-borders-of-its-container-in-ie9)

The difference is that in my case I need to have the z-index (and therefore position) set on the container. You can see my JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/qbaH9/4/

In the full layout there is an element that I "slide under" the header by adding z-index: 100 to the header, as you can see in [this image](http://cl.ly/1J1Z1S3u1t1t1y0R463Q).

How do I keep the z-index set on the header, and also make sure the dropdown isn't cutoff in IE9?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: relative` from the `.main-header`.

http://jsfiddle.net/qbaH9/3/

Comment: Thanks for answering! However, removing the positioning is effectively the same as removing the z-index value since z-index only effects positioned elements. If I remove the z-index or positioning from main-header then the element behind the header (shown here: http://cl.ly/1J1Z1S3u1t1t1y0R463Q) is moved infront of the header (show here: http://cl.ly/0C1k2g0n0U1g2Q0H0C1T) so that solution doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'd need to see the markup for that "slide-out" to better answer the question.

Comment: I have the HTML structured this way because of how my PHP framework is setup, but, maybe I could just move the 2nd navigation (account-links) to a different spot? I'm not opposed to restructuring the HTML

Comment: fyi I added a separate style sheet for IE that removes the positioning and simply has less of the style features we use (no rounded corners, no tucked in .account-navigation menu) which is working fine for now - but still makes me sad I don't know what was wrong.